# Android Studio/ IntelliJ IDEA Working Hours

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, project-management

Is there any plugin or tool which is capable of measuring how many hours do I work on a project?
Or is there any way to check how many hours do I work on specific things?
I'm going to do some freelancing stuff and it will be paid in the number of working hours.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a great tool: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7425-wakatime

Not only tracks the time but also gives some extra info too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this plugin

> A Time tracking plugin which automatically tracks the time spent on each project.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/47-time-tracker-plugin

> plugin for IntelliJ IDEs to track and record user activity.

https://github.com/dkandalov/activity-tracker